# Capturing data from a web page using PYTHON

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

I want to capture texts from the below link and save it. 
http://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=FWD&product=RR5&format=CI&version=44&glossary=0

I need to save only the texts after **.A**, so I do not need the other texts in the page. Moreover, there are 50 different links at top of the page that I want to get all of the data from all of them.

I have written the below code but it returns nothing, how can specifically get part that I need?

```
import urllib
import re
htmlfile=urllib.urlopen("http://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=FWD&product=RR5&format=CI&version=1&glossary=0")
htmltext=htmlfile.read()
regex='<pre class="glossaryProduct">(.+?)</pre>'
pattern=re.compile(regex)
out=re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
print (out)
```

I also used the following that returns all the content of the page:

```
import urllib
file1 = urllib.urlopen('http://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=FWD&product=RR5&format=txt&version=1&glossary=0')
s1 = file1.read()
print(s1)
```

Can you help me to do so?

Comment: Heed one of the commandments of modern programming: Do not regex [x/html content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1422451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not capturing anything because your content starts with a newline, and you did not enable your `.` to include newlines. If you change your compile line to

`pattern=re.compile(regex,re.S)`

It should work.

Also you may want to look at:

https://regex101.com

It shows you EXACTLY what your regex is doing. When i put the S flag on the right side, it started working exactly as it should:

[Image of regex working with the S flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mfx1.png)

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.